# Does a VoIP APNS Push Payload Contain the SIP Invite?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, pushkit

I am looking to integrate APNS for VoIP into our app and the part that I cannot seem to find anywhere is whether or not you are supposed to pass the SIP INVITE in the payload for the APNS Push. This seems like how it would happen especially since they give you double the size of the payload for a regular push notification. I have read Apples documentation and searched to see if other people and companies that have implemented this in their VoIP apps send the SIP INVITE in the payload but cannot find an answer. Hoping someone on here will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, VoIP apple push is nothing to do with SIP or SIP invite.

In reality when end-user device gets push, device needs just to register to remote server and after this to receive a call. Below you can find full steps:

1) A calling B via SIP. SIP Invite from A received by PBX/sip proxy or server.

2) PBX suspend this transaction/call and runs some custom script to send APNS push

3) Push is received by B device.

4) B device registers to PBX via SIP.

5) PBX see that now B device is available and it sends call to B via SIP protocol.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple will ban apps (in iOS 13 or higher), which use VoIP-pushes in this way. They require a permanent connection to the SIP-server, which exists before push notifications are sent.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. VoIP pushes(Or as I called them here APNS pushes) is what apple provides and recommends to use: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/supporting_pushkit_notifications_in_your_app In my example application do not need permanent connection, that why we are utilizing VoIP pushes from apple. If there were permanent connection to server, why would we ever bothered to use any kind of VoIP or APNS push? There will be no points 2,3 & 4. Just 1 & 5.